# PHP: How to get combination with the most matches of the sub-arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, statistics, combinations

I have an `$myArray` with sub-arrays which always contain 5 numbers - the numbers are sorted by size and can not be repeated in the sub-array, but there can be more "identical" sub-arrays (sub-arrays with the same numbers) in `$myArray`.

```
$myArray = array(
array(1,2,3,4,5),
array(5,6,10,18,20),
array(1,2,3,4,5),
array(2,3,4,5,9),
array(1,2,3,7,9),
array(1,3,4,5,7),
array(2,3,4,7,9),
array(2,4,5,10,29),
array(1,8,10,11,15) // etc.
);
```

How can I get an combination (array) of `$n` numbers where this combination (or rather the 5-number combinations generated from this $n-number combination) will match the most of the sub-arrays of `$myArray`?

**Example**: the desired result for `$n=7` for the `$myArray` would be **`array(1,2,3,4,5,7,9)`** because there are twenty one 5-number combinations in total derived from this result:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,7
1,2,3,4,9
//... and so on
```

and these combinations would match almost all sub-arrays (only second and last two sub-arrays are out of range).

I have tried counting with `array_count_values()` but simple frequency of all numbers doesn't work in this case...

Answer (score 0):

```
                        class Combinations implements Iterator
                        {
                            protected $c = null;
                            protected $s = null;
                            protected $n = 0;
                            protected $k = 0;
                            protected $pos = 0;

                            function __construct($s, $k) {
                                if(is_array($s)) {
                                    $this->s = array_values($s);
                                    $this->n = count($this->s);
                                } else {
                                    $this->s = (string) $s;
                                    $this->n = strlen($this->s);
                                }
                                $this->k = $k;
                                $this->rewind();
                            }
                            function key() {
                                return $this->pos;
                            }
                            function current() {
                                $r = array();
                                for($i = 0; $i < $this->k; $i++)
                                    $r[] = $this->s[$this->c[$i]];
                                return is_array($this->s) ? $r : implode('', $r);
                            }
                            function next() {
                                if($this->_next())
                                    $this->pos++;
                                else
                                    $this->pos = -1;
                            }
                            function rewind() {
                                $this->c = range(0, $this->k);
                                $this->pos = 0;
                            }
                            function valid() {
                                return $this->pos >= 0;
                            }
                            //
                            protected function _next() {
                                $i = $this->k - 1;
                                while ($i >= 0 && $this->c[$i] == $this->n - $this->k + $i)
                                    $i--;
                                if($i < 0)
                                    return false;
                                $this->c[$i]++;
                                while($i++ < $this->k - 1)
                                    $this->c[$i] = $this->c[$i - 1] + 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }







            $tickets = array(
                 array(1,2,3,4,5),
                 array(5,6,10,18,20),
                 array(1,2,3,4,5),
                 array(2,3,4,5,9),
                 array(1,2,3,7,9),
                 array(1,3,4,5,7),
                 array(2,3,4,7,9),
                 array(2,4,5,10,29),
                 array(1,8,10,11,15) // etc.
            );
    // first we need to find all numbers  that are actually in one of the arrays.

            foreach($tickets as $anArray) {
                foreach($anArray as $aNumberUsed){
                    $numbersUsed[$aNumberUsed] = $aNumberUsed;
                } 
            }
  // next we assign the number of integers in the set we are looking for.       
            $r = 7;
// next we run the above class on our array (which gets us all of the possible combinations of these numbers).
            foreach(new Combinations($numbersUsed, 7) as $comboKey => $substring){
                $comboList[$comboKey] = $substring;
                $countWins = 0;
// here we loop through all of the 5 number arrays, and flag any array who has all the variables in this iteration of the possible numbers.  There are cleaner ways to do this, but this is easy to understand.
                foreach($tickets as $valueList) {
                    $countNumbersFound = 0;
                    foreach($valueList as $value) {
                        if(in_array($value, $substring)) {
                            $countNumbersFound++;
                        }
                    }
                    if($countNumbersFound == 5) {
                        $countWins++;
                    }       
                }
                $foundCount[$comboKey] = $countWins;
            }
    $bigly = max($foundCount);


    $key = array_search($bigly, $foundCount);

    foreach($comboList[$key] as $wellDone) {
        echo "$wellDone ,";
    }
```

The class is blatantly stolen from here: http://www.developerfiles.com/combinations-in-php/

Everything after the class is original.  I don't believe in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: No, I don't have `array(1,2,3,4,5,7,9)` - this is what I want, the desired result -> I want the combination which will cover the most of the sub-arrays... And for the `$myArray` it is this combination - but I don't know how to figure it up.

Comment: Your instructor should be happy with this code, particularly if you clean up the structure that loops through to compare values  with the list values.

Comment: There are some things you could do to speed it up.    For example, you could identify all duplicates in the $myArray, and flag them to be counted once per duplicate.   Another thing you could do is change the list when you are setting the numbers used, and set each entry to a count of the number of times it appears.  ($numbersUsed[$aNumberUsed] = $aNumberUsed;